# Why won't vue.js update the DOM?

Tags: vue.js

Working my way learning about Vue. I chose it as the better alternative after looking at React, Angular and Svelte.

I have a simple example that its not working probably because I'm not getting/understanding the reactive behaviour of Vue.

Plain simple App:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <router-view />
    <app-footer></app-footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from './components/Header.vue'
import Home from './components/Home.vue'
import Footer from './components/Footer.vue'
export default {
  components: {
    name: 'App',
    'app-header': Header,
    'app-footer': Footer
  }
}
</script>
```

Where Home.vue and Footer.vue have plain HTML content on the template.

On Header.vue I have:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>The Header</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Curr Player:&nbsp;{{ ethaccount }}</li>

        <li>Prop owner:&nbsp;{{ propOwner }}</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <hr />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      ethaccount: 'N/A',
      propOwner: 'N/A'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    update() {
      var ethaccount = '0xAAAAAA123456789123456789123456789'
      console.log('ETH Account: ' + ethaccount)

      var propOwner = '0xPPPPPPPPPPP987654321987654321'
      console.log('Prop Account: ' + propOwner)
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.update()
  }
}
</script>
```

But I'm unable to get the header updated and unable to find what I'm doing wrong. Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to read a little bit more about the reactivity of the datas in vuejs check this link : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

If you need to access/change your data try to do it like that :

```
this.$data.ethaccount = 'foo';
this.$data.propOwner = 'bar';
```

For me the problem is taht you re-declare your variable locally by doing :

```
var ethaccount = "0xAA...";
```

By doing such you never change the value of the data you're accessing through your template.

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, thanks, the $this.data.XXX trick works.... I added the "var" to each variable because I was getting "variable foobar is not defined". So I understand that adding that makes the variables local. Im still not getting how I should properly address the reactive variables.

Comment: In Vue.js props and data are reactive. if you send to the children a variable it will be a prop and you can update the variable through the parent (data down, event up).
The way to access data and props is the same : this.$props.foo    this.$data.bar

Hope it helps.